# Accessing server on private network

Tags: networking, routing, proxy

I have several IP based data-loggers behind a customers' gateways/proxies/etc. Around every couple hours, the data-loggers will act as clients and initiate communication in order to upload trend data to a server called BOX which has a public IP, and upon an acceptable response from BOX, the data-loggers will no longer attempt to transfer the data.  It is assumed that the customer has configured their network to allow such communication.

Now my question.

BOX periodically needs to act as a client and initiate a request from the data-loggers who should now act as servers.  Without having the customer perform custom network configuration, is this possible?  My uncertainty is how the server located outside of the private network will be able to access the individual data-logger clients?  When the data-loggers act as clients, I understand they send header packets with their transmissions to allow them to receive the response (at least for HTTP).  Perhaps these same header packets can be used several hours later for BOX to directly send them a request?

Comment: You need IPv6. With that, you can initiate communication from either end, subject to appropriate firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Any reasonable customers have firewalls in their networks that prevent connections from outside networks.

The configuration needed on the firewalls depends on the network structure, and is different on each customer.

Comment: Bummer!  What if the data-logger periodically initiated a request to ask if BOX needed anything, and BOX responded with what it needed, and the data-logger sends the data?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't all systems be servers, with client apps?

A computer can be both a server and a client at the same time.  It's not mutually exclusive unless there's a poor design in which you're utilizing the same ports.

In the instance where you have local systems and remote systems, each behind their own firewalls, having NAT or port-forwarding in place to manage how traffic is managed can resolve the issue for you.  You just need to determine how you want to manage incoming traffic to your local systems.  Your obvious problems would be if the remote system needed to access a specific local system versus the remote system needing to access a random local system.  If you explicitly determine how the remote system determines which local system to communicate with and building the NAT appropriately, you should be able to manage this.

A good example of this would be hosting multiple webservers on different ports; like, 80, 8080 or 443, 7443, 8443, 9443, etc...  In this instance, you could have remote systems connecting to local systems based on port.

Or, if you can re-write the data-logging app, you could send HTTP headers or POST data with username, password, server name, location, etc...  This can be used to identify the sending location and the type of request (push or pull).  There are lots of different ways to accomplish what you want to do, but it depends on how much of it you manage and how much you can change.

Comment: Thanks CIA.  I agree the devices will both act as servers and clients.  Don't wish to require the customer to set up port forwarding.  I don't know much about NAT and need to learn up on it.  Will NAT accomplish my goal?  Yes, I could re-write the data-logging app, and could send HTTP headers with username/password/etc.  With this information, would could the remote client (BOX) be able to get past the customer's firewall and initiate a request to the data-logger?

Comment: Companies do this already.  Examples are SAN storage companies, like Dell and Nimble.  SANs send telemetry data back to corporate HQ and HQ logs it into their database.  HQ's servers check back with the customer's SAN on a regular basis to make sure everything's ok, then logs it.  If the remote system has access to the internet, it is already bypassing the firewall.  Just make sure your local systems are allowed to receive communication from certain IP addresses (this can be done with a regular firewall permit rule or a NAT), then get your app to read incoming data; HTTP post is an option.

Comment: I thought the request IP can easily be spoofed.  Would a company so readily allow inputs from a given IP?  Maybe if set up to only allow access to given servers within the private network?  BOX could easily access the public IP, but how does it reach a specific server on the private network without using port forwarding?

Comment: That's what authentication is for.

Comment: Recommended link to read up on authentication?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Level_Authentication seems to discuss remote desktop.  Is this what I want?

Comment: No... you need to build a server/client authentication module for your application; either doing a handshake (where the server and client verify who they are to each other) or building a credential system where the client application provides a passphrase or key that can be verified in the server's database.  This is getting into more of a stackoverflow question than a serverfault question.

Comment: Was originally going to post it on stackoverflow.  Regardless, you gave me some great tips!  Let me do a little research.  Thank you